# Serialization on Avro union types with node.js

Tags: avro

I am trying to decode an Avro schema with union types.

Considering this schema,

```
{
  "namespace": "com.car",
  "name": "Vehicle",
  "type": "record",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "name",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Given payload to be produced to Kafka

```
{"name":"my_car_name"}
```

However when consuming and payload was decoded, the output contains the type information `string`

```
{"name":{"string":"my_car_name"}}
```

I was expecting this (same as original payload)

```
{"name":"my_car_name"}
```

Refering back to the specification on json encoding it seems this is the designed behavior https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.11.1/specification/#json-encoding

How can I workaround this limitation?

I have tried to consume and decode the payload however the expectation of the output is not what I think of.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is to not use union types.

The type key is necessary for the serializer to know what type the field actually is